# not working in snowflake - "IFF" statement

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to implement below statement in Snowflake view

IFF("Closed" = TRUE,DATEDIFF(DAY,TO_DATE("ActualFinishDate"),current_date()),FALSE) - get True/False

and it wont work
if I give
IFF("Closed" = TRUE,'1234',FALSE) - this works and i get 1234 or False based on value of closed

can someone please help me why DATEDIFF(DAY,TO_DATE("ActualFinishDate"),current_date()) is not giving result within IFF
I tested the statement is correct and right value if i execute it separately.

Comment: What error message do you get, and what data type is the column "Closed"?

Comment: no error message IFF("Closed" = TRUE,DATEDIFF(DAY,TO_DATE("ActualFinishDate"),current_date()),FALSE)  resuLTS TRUE/FALSE AND IFF("Closed" = TRUE,'1234',FALSE) 1234/FALSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about data types

[CASE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/case.html)

> In the second form of CASE, each value is a potential match for expr. The value can be a literal or an expression. The value must be the same data type as the expr, or **must be a data type that can be cast to the data type of the expr.**

The difference is as follow:

```
DATEDIFF returns INTEGER, BOOLEAN
vs
'1234'   string literal,  BOOLEAN
```

And for Booelan it works as follow:

> [TO_BOOLEAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_boolean.html):
>
> ```
> For a text expression, string must be:
>
>         'true', 't', 'yes', 'y', 'on', '1' return TRUE.
>
>         'false', 'f', 'no', 'n', 'off', '0' return FALSE.
>
>         All other strings return an error.
>
> Strings are case-insensitive.
>
> For a numeric expression:
>
>         0 returns FALSE.
>
>         All non-zero values return TRUE.
> ```

EDIT:

In order to return string instead of boolean explicit cast could be used:

```
IFF("Closed" = TRUE,TO_VARCHAR(DATEDIFF(DAY,TO_DATE("ActualFinishDate"),current_date())),FALSE)

-- "Closed" column is probably boolean so there is no need to ` = TRUE`:
IFF("Closed",TO_VARCHAR(DATEDIFF(DAY,TO_DATE("ActualFinishDate"),current_date())),FALSE)
```

Comment: SO what should i do in this case? I want value and not TRUE

Comment: @astonishingme if you want to return string instead of boolean like in second example  then: `IFF("Closed" = TRUE,TO_VARCHAR(DATEDIFF(DAY,TO_DATE("ActualFinishDate"),current_date())),FALSE)`

Comment: AWESOME! thanks... it worked